# Combine two Json animation files in to one Json file

Tags: json, animation

We're exporting animations from Spine 2D as Json files, so far each animation has its own separate Json file, is it possible to combine multiple Json animations in to one Json file and how?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: Will the software support the combined files? What tools to you have access to to combine the files? You can do it with Notepad, but its faster and more secure to use a programming language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using Sublime for editing the code in typescript. At the moment we're testing if the software will support the combined files, but in order to test it we must first combine them.